# Expression Engine SafeCracker Formatting a Date Field format=”%d/%m/%Y” = 01/01/1970

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine, safecracker

Hi I am trying to format my date field which is called {member_birthday} with the format attribute. But whenever I apply the attribute to the tag it shows the date in the correct format but the with an incorrect date.

**Code:**

```
<input type="text" name="display_birthday" id="display_birthday" value="{member_birthday}" maxlength="23" size="25"/>
```

Displays the correct date i.e 1982-11-08 12:00 AM

```
<input type="text" name="display_birthday" id="display_birthday" value="{member_birthday format="%d/%m/%Y"}" maxlength="23" size="25"/>
```

Displays an incorrect date i.e 01/01/1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the date format function does not work within a safecracker tag http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/7449#25153, so I installed this plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nice-date and used this code

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{member_birthday}" format="%d/%m/%Y"}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this down the road, the statement "EE doesn't give you access to date formatting functions in templates" is simply not true. Within a Channel Entries loop, any "date" field will accept and interpret the "format" parameter. If it doesn't, something else is wrong.

Comment: Actually, this confirms that the problem was that the date was issued as a string, not as a date. So neat enough solution - if you have a string, not a date in your hand.

Comment: My field is definitely a date field in EE, but weather or not safeCracker passes it as a date I don't know. This was the only solution I found that worked. As regards to my first statement I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `member_birthday` is a string (or DateTime object), but to format as a date it has to be an integer.

Convert member_birthday to an integer before formatting. Use `strtotime` if you have access to the safe cracker code, or you could use a PHP executable block in the template to pre-parse as a variable. But if you can do those, then you can also format them without the template anyway!

Edit: http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Dates_Explained recommends:

> Always use the [Localization](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/localization.html) functions to convert between EE and Unix
>   timestamps if you are reading or writing database timestamps directly.

Comment: Wouldn't coding it in SafeCracker force all Date field types to become a certain format? But yes you are right I could turn PHP on in the template and manipulate this with PHP date functions. I am just learning EE and was more looking for a standard way that EE would like you to handle this type of situation.

Comment: I don't know safe cracker so can't comment on how it handles dates - but if this is a "custom field" then that custom field will be a string.

Comment: It is a date field from a channel. Does EE still save this as a string?

Comment: If it is a date field, the documentation says what you are doing is correct http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#date-fields but this is safe cracker, which is a user written extension, and the quality of user quieten extensions is often questionable - so that might be different? For now, do a var_dump in the template to check what type you are holding.

Comment: Sorry for a possible noob question, but how would you do a var_dump() on an EE tag? <?php var_dump({member_birthday}); ?>  and <?php var_dump($member_birthday); ?> both gave me errors

Comment: I can't remember - I'd need to check the EE code, but the variables are in a huge array, if I remember correctly. Been a while since I hacked EE (as I got fed up with fighting with issues like this).

Comment: Clarification: SafeCracker may have started as a third-party add-on, but it has been an official first-party module, bundled with ExpressionEngine, for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 0):

If your `member_birthday` field is indeed a native EE date custom field, then the date will be stored is a UNIX timestamp, and your code should work.

So my guess is that you're not using a native EE date field, or you are, but are somehow bypassing proper validation when entering the data (and thus ending up with the ISO-style date-time string in your database).

Have a look in your database (`exp_channel_data` table) to see how that field data is being stored. Try entering a date via the control panel as well, and see how that entry turns out.

Comment: In exp_channel_fields the field_type = date and in exp_channel_data the data for that field is definitely a UNIX timestamp. I entered my birthday into the field in the backend (08/11/1982) then checked the db which had changed to 405596816 but it still came out as 01/01/1970. Starting to think this is an EE bug

Comment: What if you display the same field via a Channel Entries tag instead of within a SafeCracker form? Does the formatting work then?